# Regex expression to find value in string that has a static position but variable amount of characters

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am reading in data from a PDF, and the output is a block of text. The goal is to pull out one value from that block of text. The value I need to pull is in a static position, but the amount of characters can change. What is regex expression to find the string in question.

The block of text I am using is as follows:

```
Residue mmbtu 3,787.11 100.00% 3,787.11 $1.623163 $6,147.10 
Total 3,787.11 3,787.11 $6,147.10
```

I need to find the dollar amount after the line with "Total" which in this case is `6,147.10`

The expression that has yielded the best so far is `(?<=\$)([^\s]+)`, however this gives me the numbers after the dollar sign excluding spaces. I need to to only find the last value though

```
(?<=\$)([^\s]+)
```

The expected result would be to find the dollar amount that comes after the line with the word "Total" knowing that any PDF that I read in will have a block of text similar to what is posted above. The example above would give me a value of 6,147.10

Comment: Maybe `(?<=\$)\S+$`?

Comment: Do you mean like this using a capturing group? `^Total.* \$(.+)$`

Comment: Perhaps [`^Total[^$]+(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/kP11Je/1/) ?

Comment: Hey Wiktor, that expression doesn't bring back any value. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/bI9hzF/1 - it returns what you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Interesting that the program you posted does actually recognize the expression correctly. Jan works as well. However, I am using https://regexr.com/ to test expression becasue my program (UiPath) apparently recognizes that format instead, and that site does not show the right answer.

Comment: In UiPath, I have to assign a string variable and use an expresstion like this system.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(str_ResVolMCF,"(?<=Res Return )([^\s]+)").ToString  to get the program to understand

Comment: Ok i see the problem! There is an ending space after the last value. When it is removed, the expressions everyone has posted works, but when there is a space, then it fails. Any way to get around this?

Comment: Then just use `(?<=\$)\S+(?=\s*$)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
^Total[^$]+(.+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/kP11Je/1/).